# Use Multiple CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

Cannot figure out how to use multiple CTE

This fails

```
; with [cteOne] as (
  select 1 as col
),
  [cteTwo]  as (
  select 2 as col
)
select 'yesA' where exists (select * from [cteOne])
select 'yexB' where exists (select * from [cteTwo])
```

This works - but this is not what I need

```
; with [cteOne] as (
  select 1 as col
),
  [cteTwo]  as (
  select 2 as col
)
select * from [cteOne]
union 
select * from [cteTwo]
```

The real syntax was a join to row_number() partition
I just ended up using a derived table

Comment: Your example doesn't need multiple CTEs. You could use two single ones. Can you show something more representative of why you need it? In any event they are only in scope for the single statement immediately following. You can't return 2 separate result sets from one definition.

Comment: What is it what you need? Please post the resultset you expected to see

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why can't you just put a `union` into the first example?

Comment: I know this sample does not need multiple CTE.  I have more complex tsql that needs a format like the first.

Comment: Well it isn't possible and as we have no idea what the "more complex" case is we can't suggest the best alternative. If you need to reference a CTE in multiple statements you can just repeat it or create a view instead. Or maybe the statements could be combined. Or maybe it should be materialized into a temp table.

Comment: @MartinSmith  I need TSQL syntax.  I just substituted an inline derived table.

Comment: For anyone else who was searching for information on how to use multiple CTEs in one query, this question/answer may be of some use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140750/keeping-it-simple-and-how-to-do-multiple-cte-in-a-query

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first one fails because a CTE or set of CTEs can only be followed by a single statement.

You could rewrite it as

```
; with [cteOne] as (
  select 1 as col
)
select 'yesA' where exists (select * from [cteOne])

; with [cteTwo]  as (
  select 2 as col
)
select 'yexB' where exists (select * from [cteTwo])
```

Comment: I came to the same conclusion.  I definitely don't like that behavior.

Comment: Why is it required to have the colon before the with statement? ";WITH" Thanks

Comment: @Drewdin It's not, technically. But it is required to have a semi-colon after the previous statement, unlike many other statements, so a semi-colon before the with ensures that if you're not used to using semi-colon separators.

Comment: Thanks, i have seen it a few times and didn't understand why