# Use SQL Server CTE to retrieve multiple result sets

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I was wondering how I can retrieve multiple result sets based on one CTE? Something like what I have below - but obviously this doesn't work.

Does anyone know how I can get these 2 (or more) sets of data, based on that one CTE? (more, as in that it would be nice to get the total record count from this same CTE as well.)

```
;WITH CTE AS  
(
  SELECT 
      Column1, Column2, Column3 
  FROM 
      Product 
  WHERE 
      Name LIKE '%Hat%' AND Description Like '%MyBrand%'
)
SELECT DISTINCT CategoryId FROM CTE
SELECT DISTINCT BrandId FROM CTE
```

Comment: I have seen some examples that managed to get the count and one result set at the same time. But i couldn't find anything that produces multiple result sets.

Comment: If you need something like this then you should probably use either a table variable or a temp table, not a CTE

Comment: I agree with @Lamak. I was going to suggest adding ' into #tempTable ' to your CTE query and using the new temp table for subsequent queries.

Comment: An ugly way that would work for this specific scenario: `;WITH CTE AS (...) SELECT 'C' AS ItemType, CategoryID FROM CTE UNION SELECT 'B', BrandID FROM CTE`. Pull the rows from your result where `ItemType='C'`  to get categories, and where `ItemType='B'` for the brands.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use Multiple CTE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924746/use-multiple-cte)

Comment: Not just that it can't be done.  It should not be done.  A CTE is just syntax is evaluated.  If you going to use the results more than once then typically you should persist to #temp or table variable.

Comment: Yep, as i said. Clear. It was just that for some time it looked to me like something that could fit into what i wanted to accomplish.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A CTE only exists for the query immediately following it, so it's not possible to use it for two separate select statements. You'll either need to persist the data in something like a temp table, or construct/invoke the CTE twice.

Comment: Alright, that's totally clear then. Seeing some of those examples, looked like it could be done, but, i get the point, it's just not possible.